Unable to determine what CMake generator to use when using Cmake: Configure command (VScode, windows 11)
I made a fresh new project from an empty folder using the quick start command. In the folder are the cmakelists.txt and main.cpp files only. When running any command (such as Configure, Edit Cache...), I get this error output:
[proc] The command: ninja --version failed with error: Error: spawn ninja ENOENT
[proc] The command: ninja-build --version failed with error: Error: spawn ninja-build ENOENT
[proc] The command: make --version failed with error: Error: spawn make ENOENT
[main] Unable to determine what CMake generator to use. Please install or configure a preferred generator, or update settings.json, your Kit configuration or PATH variable. Error: No usable generator found.

I have already tried reinstalling gcc, installing MSYS2 and using pacman to install gcc, g++, and cmake, reseting Cmake tools extension, editing the system PATH variable, and editing cmake.cmakePath to the location of the pacman install (C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe). Is there anything else I should consider?

Have you installed pacman -S ninja or pacman -S make?

Can you post you cmake commandline invokation? Remember that cmake is only a generator
